# scroll bar visual basic properties

Tags: vb.net

I work on project with scroll bars. Each scroll bar holds a max value of 255 (the color codes) 1 scroll bar is red, second green third blue. When I change the large value property from 1 to 5 (it is required in the project) and slide the scroll bar all the way to the end the final value is 251 instead of 255 and it must be 255. Small change is set to 1. I am currently learning vb, does anyone know how to solve this issue?
 Here is the code I have and we are not allowed to use variables yet
The explicit option must be on as well as the strict.

Option Explicit On 
Option Strict On

Public Class frmMixer

```
Private Sub cmdExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click
    Application.Exit()

End Sub

Private Sub hsbRed_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles hsbRed.ValueChanged
    lblRed.Text = Convert.ToString(hsbRed.Value)
    picColor.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(hsbRed.Value, hsbGreen.Value, hsbBlue.Value)
End Sub
Private Sub hsbGreen_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles hsbGreen.ValueChanged
    lblGreen.Text = Convert.ToString(hsbGreen.Value)
    picColor.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(hsbGreen.Value, hsbGreen.Value, hsbBlue.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub hsbBlue_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles hsbBlue.ValueChanged
    lblBlue.Text = Convert.ToString(hsbBlue.Value)
    picColor.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(hsbRed.Value, hsbGreen.Value, hsbBlue.Value)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: A scrollbar has a thumb, the thingamabob that you drag.  Sort of obvious when it is all the way at the top, that's 0.  So the top of the thumb indicates the position.  Does it still do that when you drag it all the way down, isn't the bottom of the thumb that now indicates position?  Or is it still the top?  Think about it.

Comment: When I drag, the value still only goes to 251 instead of 255 because the large value is set to 5 instead of 1. When I click at the arrows the value is 255 because the small change is set to 1. I cannot change the maximum value from 255 to 260 to accommodate for this difference I get error when compiling. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Change large change property for the scroll bar to 1 (my project started at 10 and changing it to 1 solved it)

Click the scrollbar -> properties window should show
Scroll down to "LargeChange" property and change to 1